# How to dynamically create tables for a user-defined DbContext in EF Core as a third party library

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a library where users can connect "any" database (that EF supports, of course) to it, then I can do some operations on that database.

**My problem** is that I can't create a table in a database at runtime, because the `DbContext` is given to me at runtime, I just have an instance of it.

Consider this:

```cs
public async Task InitAsync<T>(T context) where T : DbContext
{
    await context.CreateTableFor<Person>();
    context.Set<Person>().Where(p => p.Name = "")..etc
}
```

I need something like `CreateTableFor` to create a table.

The fields of `Person` are known at compile time, but I can't find an elegant solution to do migrations on a `DbContext` that is not under my control.

I've seen similar situations like [hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) which stores data in a database that you specify and it creates its own tables, but it does **not** use EF Core.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What library should do? Maybe you can use different approach and add extensions for ModelBuilder.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv the library is an abstraction for storing configurations/sessions for another library, ext over model builder? to be called in the onModelCreating ? hmm

Comment: Well, then it is simple. Define Extension method over `ModelBuilder`, something like this: `ModelBuilder DefineConfigurationStorage (this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` - define in this method your entity `modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()` and create instruction for library usage that this method should be called in `OnModelCreating`. Then EF Core will create all needed tables and migrations automatically.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I tried that and i got the this error: `error CS7069: Reference to type 'ReferenceOwnershipBuilder<,>' claims it is defined in 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore', but it could not be found`, the weird thing is that its a compile time error, its like ef core already knows im injecting something that is not suppose to be there lol

Comment: i removed `entity=> entity.ToTable()` call and the error is gone, but its not creating any tables, ( I did call the `database.migrate`)

Comment: manually doing `dotnet ef migrations add init` gets the job done but i was looking for a way to automatically build the tables without actually need the user to call anything

Comment: User should have migrations already. What you are trying to do is hacky and  is bad idea. What i have proposed is configuring user’s context with registering your entities.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I think there are no options anyway

Comment: What does it mean there are no options? There are a tons of options, i have proposed simplest and Provider agnostic. But you cannot register additional entity in already created/configured context. This registration is strictly immutable. IOW you should create tables by yourself for each DataProvider and run selects/updates via raw SQL.